# rich:calendar displays a date in far future when Thailand is selected

Tags: jsf, internationalization, richfaces, jsf-2.2

I have an application that works with 5 countries and their local languages. The `rich:calendar` seems to be working fine with all countries. Except, when i select Thailand and Thai language.
I see some odd date like `1st January 2559` in my calendar when i click on it. For rest of the languages it works fine. What can be the issue. Below is my code.

```
<rich:calendar id="schoolStartDate" 
enableManualInput="true"
datePattern="#{myController.datePattern}"
styleClass="inputreqschoolday" 
showApplyButton="false"
defaultvalue="#{actionForm.progressForm.detailsForm.schoolStartDate}"
showInput="true"
value="#{myController.progressForm.detailsForm.schoolStartDate}"
locale="#{schoolManagedBean.sessionData.countryLanguage}" >
<f:validator validatorId="validateDateFormat" />
<f:converter converterId="CalDateStrConverter" />
</rich:calendar>
```

Comment: Did you check `locale` and `converter` for that case?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be `rich:faces` bug. 
I was able to solve the issue by checking the date's value which was going `null`(that worked perfectly for other languages though). I dont know if it is the perfect solution.

```
handleNullValue function would set the value to currentdate.
```

I used `onShow` Attribute

```
onshow="handleNullValue('#{rich:clientId('schoolStartDate')}');"
```